# Serialized Hash field and Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, simple-form

I have the following.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  serialize :fields
end
```

The value of `fields` will depend on the category. But as an example;

```
{"address" => "8 finance street, hong kong",
 "founded" => "1973"}
```

In this example the category has defined `"address"` and `"founded"` as the custom fields.

What I want is to say;

```
= simple_form_for(@page) do |f|
  = f.association :category
  - f.object.category.fields.each do |field|
    = f.input field.name
```

But I need to do something magic to deal with the fact that `@page.founded` is not valid

Instead I should be looking at `@page.fields["founded"]`.

Any suggestions?

---

Update:

I've got slightly nearer

```
- if f.object.category
  - f.object.category.fields.each do |field|
    = f.input field.name do
      = text_field_tag "post[fields][#{field.name}]", f.object.fields[file.name]
```

Now need to make this DRYer (don't want to specify the name of the object).

I'll see if I can write a decent simple form extension for this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue trying to use `simple_fields_for` on a Hash field type of a Mongoid model.  The Mongoid version of your example I was dealing with looked like this:

```
class Page
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :fields, type: Hash
end
```

My situation might be slightly different though, as I already know the hash keys I am looking for ahead of time, and just needed `simple_fields_for` to work with the hash field.  The naive method (basic `fields_for` usage) I was using looked like this:

```
= simple_form_for(@page) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :fields do |ff|
    = ff.input :address
    = ff.input :founded
```

But that wasn't populating the form properly.  nicholaides's solution of wrapping the hash in a struct worked for me:

```
- require 'ostruct'
= simple_form_for(@page) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :fields, OpenStruct.new(@page.fields) do |ff|
    = ff.input :address
    = ff.input :founded
```

To avoid having to mix the OpenStruct stuff into my view, I created a monkey patch for `simple_form` to automatically wrap hash types in an OpenStruct and put it into an initializer:

```
require 'ostruct'

module SimpleForm::ActionViewExtensions::Builder
  def simple_fields_for_with_hash_support(*args, &block)
    if args[0] && !args[1]
      field = object.send(args[0])
      args << OpenStruct.new(field) if field.respond_to?(:has_key?)
    end
    simple_fields_for_without_hash_support(*args, &block)
  end
  alias simple_fields_for_without_hash_support simple_fields_for
  alias simple_fields_for simple_fields_for_with_hash_support
end
```

And now I can use my original naive solution without special view code.

Comment: +1 for the "f.simple_fields_for :fields, OpenStruct.new(@page.fields) do |ff|". I wrecked my brain many an hour to work out why it wasn't retrieving values properly until I added the OpenStruct bit.

Comment: This is awesome.  An added note for strong parameters users: you must define each field you add explicitly.  For example, `params.require(:page).permit(:fields => [:address, :founded])`

Comment: Thx for the solution, it works perfectly, with one exception: I do not know, how to add validation errors to `@page.fields`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html). It works like this:

```
require 'ostruct'

struct = OStruct.new("address" => "8 finance street, hong kong", "founded" => "1973")
struct.address # => 8
struct.founded # => "1973"
```

Comment: that's fine for the "callability" (I remember using a `CallableHash` back in the day`). But my specific question is about SimpleForm, really. I want a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you could easily adapt to your problem :

https://gist.github.com/2157877

Keeps the form super-clean and keeps the normal behaviour of an active model (nothing to add in your controller).

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

If only I´ve found this post earlier I would not have missed three days on this issue.

I was not able to comment on the answear so just to add, if anyone trying to `fields_for` a mongo array of hashes (has_many like) additionally you will need to supply the root OpenStruct object with a `"#{key}_attributes="` (in this case fields_attributes=) method so `fields_for` would identify it is a has_many relation.

Hope it helps someone ;)