# How to access nested child element in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to access a `Hash` type of mongoid in `fieds_for` and I already have a relationship with a model and want to access a hash of that model. Something like:

```
class Leave
  field :leaves_types, :type => Hash
end

class User
  has_many :leaves
end
```

Want to do something like:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.fields_for :leaves.leave_types...
```

How I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey!
Thank you very much. Actually, first time I'm asking question here and the ask a question view is quite inaccessible for screen readers so, some how manage to ask question and forgot formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a *block* to `fields_for`. For more information on that method [see docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many). In your case, first, add this line to your `User` model:

```
class User
  has_many :leaves
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :leaves
end
```

This is required so that when your form is posted, the attributes coming from the form fields for leaves via `params` were handled correctly.

Now your template should look like this (for simplicity by now I assume that your `Leave` also has a simple text field named `foo`):

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :leaves do |leave_fields| %>
    # Fields for a leave here ----v
    Foo: <%= leaves_fields.text_field :foo %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or, if you `@user.leaves` already initialized and you want form builder to put its values to form fields, you have to iterate over `@user.leaves`, passing each of them to `fields_for` as second argument:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
  <% @user.leaves.each do |leave| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :leaves, leave do |leave_fields| %>
      # Note the addition here --^
      Foo: <%= leave_fields.text_field :foo %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**But** your question has another one inside: you have not a text field, but a *hash*, and there is no default form input for it (i.e. there is no `f.hash_field :leaves_types`). So you may want to make it by yourself like suggested in these questions: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9613208/693538), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1002963/693538) and [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3089849/693538).

Anyway, having a Hash field seems rather uncommon to me, so maybe Hash can be somehow replaced, say, with another `has_many` association (not sure), and in this case you will only need another nested `fields_for`.

Comment: Hi NIA,

Thanks for reply. I think I need to manage it from controller it self after submitting the form. Cause, I want to store values in the hash as, leaveType id and its value.

Comment: Indeed, in this case you can avoid `Hash` by adding new model class `LeaveType` with fields `id`, `leave_id` and `value`, and add `has_many :leave_types` to `Leave`. In this case `leave_types` will return an array for which you can iterate normally and again use `fields_for`. If this still doesn't fit you well, that's maybe because I don't completely understand what "leave" and "leave type" actually mean in your business logic.