# Why I get 'undefined method' with simple_form and hstore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, hstore

I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  validates :email,
    presence: true

  serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore

end
```

and

```
<%= simple_form_for User.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :zipcode %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Sign up' %>
<% end %>
```

Why when I want to `Sign up` I get an error:

```
undefined method `zipcode' for #<User:0x007fd397631650>
```

Full trace:
https://gist.github.com/3c9df05758ea3d486989

Comment: Is zipcode an attribute in the `data` hash? If so I don't think you can access it in this manner, and I doubt that simple_form will handle handle the serialized field. Maybe this thread can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613208/serialized-hash-field-and-simple-form

Comment: and why it should work?

Answer (score 1):

`simple_form` can only create inputs for attributes of a model, and it looks like `zipcode` is not an attribute of your `User` model.

You should run a migration to add this column to your `Users` table, and then you will be able to store the zipcode of a user.